# Swift: Customizing TableView to hold multiple columns of data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

So I'm customizing a tableview to hold multiple columns. I want 3 columns, and am customizing the TableViewCell, except I'm at a roadblock.

Right now I have a TableView that is in a ViewController, and the TableView accurately holds one column of data. Here I am changing  it to three columns and I get an error about unwrapping an optional nil value.

Here's the important parts of viewcontroller with the tableview (FinishTestController.swift):

```
    var bestRank: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var bestScore: [String] = ["-----", "-----", "-----", "-----", "-----"]
var bestTime: [String] = ["-----", "-----", "-----", "-----", "-----"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addhighscore()
    loadhighscores()

    self.tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bestRank.count;;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.column1.text = self.bestRank[indexPath.row]//<-- ERROR points here
    cell.column2.text = self.bestScore[indexPath.row]
    cell.column2.text = self.bestTime[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}

func loadhighscores(){
    var result = db.query("SELECT * from EASY_MATH5 ORDER BY Score DESC, Time ASC LIMIT 5", parameters: nil)
    println("===============================")

    for row in result
    {
        bestScore[i] = row["Score"]!.asString()
        print(bestScore[i])
        bestTime[i] = row["Time"]!.asString()
        println(bestTime[i])

        i++
    }
}
```

Here's my cell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var column1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var column2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var column3: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

And here's the error I get:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

and points to the line that says "cell.column1.text = self.bestRank[indexPath.row]" with a line "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION".

Any idea on how to resolve?

Comment: do these columns exist in the storyboard? and did you create the IBOutlet connection?

Comment: @LukePatterson Yes, I have 3 labels on my storyboard, each connected to the TableViewCell labels. the labels in the storyboard are in a prototype cell that's connected to the tableviewcell class, and the tableview they are in is connected to the finishtest class, which is where the first block of code in my question comes from

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint at that line.  Check to see that `cell` is initialized, and that the labels you are trying to populate are not nil as well.    If the cell is nil, the TableViewCell class is probably not registered properly.  If the labels are nil, it's probably a similar registration issue.

Comment: Shouldn't the labels I try to populate be nil before I populate them?

Comment: No.  The label itself should be initialized, but the label text could be empty.

Comment: I see that cell is initialized but column1 = (UILabel!) nil along with column2 and column3. Does that mean I didn't connect column1 correctly? hm

Comment: Did you set the class of the prototype cell in the storyboard to your custom `TableViewCell` class?

Comment: Yep, Style: Custom, Identifier: cell, class: TableViewCell, and all 3 labels in the storyboard are connected to the three IBOutlet labels in TableViewCell class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113774/discussion-between-djohnson-and-milap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
self.tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

From `viewDidLoad()`, you don't need to register your `UITableViewCell` subclass if you're using prototype cells.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I **made minor adjustments** which I've **noted in the comments** with "// nb: " - it works fine now - once those minor points were removed.

Only other change in my code that I did, was the use of "Cell1" instead of "cell" and name of custom cell as "CustomTableViewCell" instead of "TableViewCell", but this is only from personal habit.

> class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var bestRank : [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var bestScore: [String] = ["-----", "-----", "-----", "-----", "-----"]
var bestTime: [String] = ["-----", "-----", "-----", "-----", "-----"]

// --------------------------------------
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.bestRank.count  // nb: use of "self." and no ";;" at end
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.column1.text = self.bestRank[indexPath.row]
    cell.column2.text = self.bestScore[indexPath.row]
    cell.column3.text = self.bestTime[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// --------------------------------------
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
// --------------------------------------

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // nb: Not used: "self.tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")"
```

// nb: Datasource + delegate already assigned with tableview in storyboard with click-drag-drop into ViewController.
    }

---

CustomCell was done like yours...

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var column1: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var column2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var column3: UILabel!
```

** Results = No Error **
Simulator showing table as you wanted...

[image]

Comment: The problem was registerClass is not necessary when using prototype cells. When I removed that my code worked. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score -1):

You should most likely be using a UICollectionView for this type of behaviour.

With a collection view you will have more control of the layout of each cell.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/

Comment: This does not answer the question asked about an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` exception.